# Probability of picking a ball that has already previously been picked

Tags: probability

Given $n$ unique balls, you pick out a fraction $f$ of them and put them back. You then repeat. 
What is the probability $p$ as a function of the number of iterations $t$ of picking a ball that has already previously been picked?

For instance, if $n=3$ and a single ball is picked each iteration ($f=\frac{1}{3}$), $p(t)=0,\frac{1}{3},\frac{5}{9},\frac{19}{27},...$, and then my brute-force-by-hand-method kinda breaks down.

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A_t$ be the number of balls which have been seen after $t$ iterations.  Then starting with $P(A_0=0)=1$, you have $$\displaystyle P(A_{t+1}=a_{t+1}|A_{t}=a_{t}) = \dfrac{{a_{t}\choose fn-a_{t+1}+a_{t}}{n-a_{t}\choose a_{t+1}-a_{t}}}{{n\choose fn}} $$ and thus $$\displaystyle P(A_{t+1}=a_{t+1})= \sum_{a_{t}} \dfrac{{a_{t}\choose fn-a_{t+1}+a_{t}}{n-a_{t}\choose a_{t+1}-a_{t}}}{{n\choose fn}} P(A_{t}=a_{t}) $$ with the probability you are looking for being  $$p(t+1) = 1- P(A_{t+1} = A_{t}+fn) = 1-\sum_{a_t} \dfrac{{n-a_{t}\choose fn}}{{n\choose fn}} P(A_{t}=a_{t}).$$

I have no idea whether this can be simplified, though $E[A_n]$ certainly can be.

In your example of $n=3$ and $fn=1$, this will give

- $P(A_{t+1}=1|A_{t}=0) =1$
- $P(A_{t+1}=1|A_{t}=1) =\frac13$
- $P(A_{t+1}=2|A_{t}=1) =\frac23$
- $P(A_{t+1}=2|A_{t}=2) =\frac23$
- $P(A_{t+1}=3|A_{t}=2) =\frac13$
- $P(A_{t+1}=3|A_{t}=3) =1$
- $P(A_{t+1}=1)= \dfrac{1}{3^t}$
- $P(A_{t+1}=2)= \dfrac{2^{t+1}-2}{3^t}$
- $P(A_{t+1}=3)= \dfrac{3^t-2^{t+1}-1}{3^t}$
- $p(t+1) = 1- P(A_{t+1} = A_{t}+1)= 1-\dfrac{2^n}{3^n}$

so your sequence continues $0, \frac{1}{3},  \frac{5}{9},  \frac{19}{27},  \frac{65}{81},  \frac{211}{243},  \frac{665}{729},  \frac{2059}{2187},  \frac{6305}{6561},  \frac{19171}{19683},  \frac{58025}{59049},  \frac{175099}{177147}, 
 \ldots$

Comment: Thank you very much! Why is the notation of $A_t=a_t$ used though? What does $a_t$ signify?

Comment: $A_t$ is a random variable representing the number of balls in total seen by time $t$, while $a_t$ represents a particular number which is one of the possible values $A_t$ might take.  So in the bullet points I have changed the $a_{t+1}$ and $a_t$ into actual numbers.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks again!

Comment: Hi again, sorry to ask this so late. I don't quite know how to use the formula for $p(t+1)$; to me it seems to be iterative in that it involves $P(A_t=a_t)$ that was computed from the previous step. If so, how did you arrive at the example formula $1-\frac{2^n}{3^n}$? Can this be done directly from reduction of the iterative formula, or do you have to analyse the combinations as thoroughly as you did in the bullet points? This seems very demanding once $n>>1$! Also, in the summations can one say in general that you sum up to something (for instance $n$) or does it depend on the system?

Comment: @Lovsovs: $p(t+1) = 1−P(A_{t+1}=A_t +1) $ $= 1 - P(A_{t+1}=1 \mid A_t=0) P(A_t=0)- P(A_{t+1}=2 \mid A_t=1) P(A_t=1) - P(A_{t+1}=3 \mid A_t=2) P(A_t=2)$ $ =    1 - 1\times 0 - \dfrac23 \times \dfrac{1}{3^{t-1}} - \dfrac13 \times \dfrac{2^t -2 }{3^{t-1}}   $ $= 1-  \dfrac{2+2^{t}-2}{3^t}$ $= 1-  \dfrac{ 2^t}{3^{t}}$